# How to run erlang app in Intellij with erlang plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

I imported my erlang project into Intellij, which uses rebar.
Dependencies are in `deps/ folder`

Example:

```
deps/cowboy
deps/emysql, etc.
```

The project was compiled successfully, but when I start console and call `myproject:start()`,it can't find the dependencies.
Do I have to build a release version with `rebar` to test?

Comment: Resolved...File->Project Structure->Dependencies

Comment: looks like an importer issue, please file a new one in https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/issues/new.